# Create solution to keep the time all the time, because after 2h the elapsedTime stop working

Tags: swift, swiftui

The code works perfect if I go to background mode and stay for less then 2 hours but if pass more time stop works, the app cant keep the backgroundTime for no limit time.

Needs to reload the webview after 120secs always, does not matter how long been on background mode.

Code:

```
    

        } .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .background:
                backgroundTime = Date()
            case .inactive:
                break
            case .active:
                if let backgroundTime = backgroundTime {
                    let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(backgroundTime)
                    if elapsedTime > 120 {
                        webview.reload()
                    }
                }
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is reliable for less than two hours then why not wait for one hour and then re-launch the timer?

Comment: You can try BackgroundTasks but there is no guaranteed way to do anything in the background. You can look up Backgrounds Modes too, if your app has a valid reason there are ways.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I've try this but still not working.